# Trying to run stat over a list if directories and perform some action if they exist in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm an Ansible newbie so please bear with me.

I have a list of directories that I need to set FACLs on. **Not all of these directories will exist on all hosts in my inventory**.  My Ansible playbook is trying to achieve the following:

-stat each directory listed in the dir_list variable file and register the results.
-Run the acl module to assign FACL permissions to any directory that exists on the server.

Here is what my variable file - dir_list - looks like:

```
dir_path:
  - /tmp/testdir1
  - /tmp/testdir2
  - /tmp/testdir3
  - /tmp/testdir4
```

Here is what my playbook looks like:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: yes
  any_errors_fatal: no
  vars_files:
    - /home/user1/ansible/dir_list
  tasks:
  - name: Check if directory exists
    stat:
      path: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      "{{ dir_path }}"
    register: dircheck

  - name: Set ACLs
    acl:
      path: "{{ item }}"
      entity: testuser
      etype: user
      permissions: rx
      state: present
    with_items: "{{ dircheck.results | selectattr('stat.isdir') | map(attribute='item') | list }}"
    when: item.stat.isdir is defined and (item.stat.isdir|bool)
```

I have obviously researched this and tried a a dozen+ suggested solutions to no avail.  The last two lines are just two of the myriad combinations I've tried.  I'm running Ansible version 2.9.10 on RHEL7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the feedback from Ansible look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*Stat each directory listed in the dir_list variable ... Run the acl module to assign FACL permissions to any directory that exists.*"**

A: Given the dirs

```sh
shell> ls -d1 /tmp/* | grep testdir
/tmp/testdir1
/tmp/testdir2
/tmp/testdir3
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dir_path:
      - /tmp/testdir1
      - /tmp/testdir2
      - /tmp/testdir3
      - /tmp/testdir4
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ dir_path }}"
      register: dircheck
    - debug:
        msg: "Set ACLs at {{ item.stat.path }}"
      loop: "{{ dircheck.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      when:
        - item.stat.exists
        - item.stat.isdir|default(false)
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [stat] ****
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir3)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir4)

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir1) => 
  msg: Set ACLs at /tmp/testdir1
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir2) => 
  msg: Set ACLs at /tmp/testdir2
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir3) => 
  msg: Set ACLs at /tmp/testdir3
skipping: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/testdir4)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Vladimir.